# #include <thread> erorr c++11

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, gcc

I'm getting an error with `#include <thread>`

The error is -

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/thread:35:0,
                 from main.cpp:35:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/c++0x_warning.h:32:2: error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.
```

But I'm compiling with c++11 like so...

`g++ main.cpp -o main -std=c++11`

Also compiling through NetBeans with c++11 selected.

gcc version 4.8.5 (SUSE Linux)

Comment: Try moving source code file name (`main.cpp`) to the end of that command line.

Comment: Same error I'm afraid.

Answer (score -2):

g++ version 4.8.5 is fairly old with only partial thread support. See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.5/libstdc++/manual/manual/status.html#status.iso.2011

Try updating your gcc suite to the latest version for your distro and you should be good.

Comment: `No update candidate for 'gcc-c++-4.8-8.4.x86_64'. The highest available version is already installed.`  using zypper on Opensuse leap

Comment: I don't have a SUSE install but you might be out of luck unless you compile the latest gcc from scratch (time consuming but straightforward). There isn't much of a way to work around a compiler that doesn't support the language feature you want to use.